# What code can i use to prevent a runtime error?

Tags: java

I am writing a program in which i prompt a user to enter a number between 1 and 44.However what code could i add in to prevent them from entering a number above that with a user friendly message and no run time error?

Comment: You cant "prevent" user from typing in console whatever he wants. All you can do is just test if his input is acceptable. If it is not then ask him to write it again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
try {

   // Your code goes here ...   

} catch(RuntimeException e) {
  // Handle RuntimeException here
  //log.warn("Something bad happened Harry... Hopefully, we can recover!", e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(number < 1 || number > 44) {
    //prompt again
}
```

**Edit:**

As mentioned in the comment, using a while loop will force your user to continue until they enter a valid number.

```
while (number < 1 || number > 44) {
    //prompt again
}
```

Comment: I think a `while` loop would be more appropriate.

Comment: @JoshM I just wanted to give user the idea of using a condition to test the number. You're right though :)